# Does the flux produced by the induced current equal, in value, the original magnetic flux or just opposes it?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Does the flux produced by the induced current equal, in value,  the  original magnetic flux or just opposes it?

Answer (score 1):

The original *change* *in* magnetic flux will induce an emf in the circuit. How much flux is produced depends on the induced current, which is given, at any instant, by $$\text{Induced current}=\frac{\text{induced emf}}{\text{resistance of circuit}}.$$
Clearly, then, the flux produced by the induced current depends on the circuit resistance, and can be changed arbitrarily, by changing the resistance. Therefore it won't, in general, equal the original flux at any instant.

**Later addition**

Let $\Phi_\text{ext}$ be the flux linkage due to external flux, and $\dot\Phi_\text{ext}$ be its rate of change.
Let $\Phi_\text{int}$ be the flux linkage due to induced current, and $\dot\Phi_\text{int}$ be its rate of change.
Then the induced emf is
$$\mathscr E=-\dot\Phi_\text{ext}+-\dot\Phi_\text{int}$$
But if $L$ is the self inductance of the circuit and $R$ its resistance,
$$\Phi_\text{int}=\frac LR \mathscr E$$
We therefore have
$$\frac RL \Phi_\text{int}=-\dot\Phi_\text{ext}-\dot\Phi_\text{int}\ \ \ \ \ \text{that is}\ \ \ \ \ \ \dot\Phi_\text{int}=-\dot\Phi_\text{ext}-\frac RL \Phi_\text{int}$$
Suppose now that $|\Phi_\text{ext}|$ rises from zero at time $t=0$, and goes on rising. At first $\Phi_\text{int}$ will be zero so $\dot\Phi_\text{int}=-\dot\Phi_\text{ext}$ and, while $t$ is very small, $\Phi_\text{int}=-\Phi_\text{ext}$. As time goes on $\Phi_\text{int}$ grows and makes the magnitude of $\dot\Phi_\text{int}$ less than that of $\dot\Phi_\text{ext}$. I find it easier to think about if I make $\dot\Phi_\text{ext}$ negative, so that $-\dot\Phi_\text{ext}$ is positive, and $\frac RL \Phi_\text{int}$ is also positive. In a nutshell, then:
$$|\Phi_\text{int}|\leq |\Phi_\text{ext}|$$